# How to cut up a string in a specific way, retaining what is useful?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I'm trying to make a program for my biology research.

I need to take this sequence:

```
NNNNNNNNNNCCNNAGTGNGNACAGACGACGGGCCCTGGCCCCTCGCACACCCTGGACCA
AGTCAATCGCACCCACTTCCCTTTCTTCTCGGATGTCAAGGGCGACCACCGGTTGGTGTT
GAGCGTCGTGGAGACCACCGTTCTGGGGCTCATCTTTGTCGTCTCACTGCTGGGCAACGT
GTGTGCTCTAGTGCTGGTGGCGCGCCGTCGGCGCCGTGGGGCGACAGCCAGCCTGGTGCT
CAACCTCTTCTGCGCGGATTTGCTCTTCACCAGCGCCATCCCTCTAGTGCTCGTCGTGCG
CTGGACTGAGGCCTGGCTGTTGGGGCCCGTCGTCTGCCACCTGCTCTTCTACGTGATGAC
AATGAGCGGCAGCGTCACGATCCTCACACTGGCCGCGGTCAGCCTGGAGCGCATGGTGTG
CATCGTGCGCCTCCGGCGCGGCTTGAGCGGCCCGGGGCGGCGGACTCAGGCGGCACTGCT
GGCTTTCATATGGGGTTACTCGGCGCTCGCCGCGCTGCCCCTCTGCATCTTGTTCCGCGT
GGTCCCGCAGCGCCTTCCCGGCGGGGACCAGGAAATTCCGATTTGCACATTGGATTGGCC
CAACCGCATAGGAGAAATCTCATGGGATGTGTTTTTTGTGACTTTGAACTTCCTGGTGCC
GGGACTGGTCATTGTGATCAGTTACTCCAAAATTTTACAGATCACGAAAGCATCGCGGAA
GAGGCTTACGCTGAGCTTGGCATACTCTGAGAGCCACCAGATCCGAGTGTCCCAACAAGA
CTACCGACTCTTCCGCACGCTCTTCCTGCTCATGGTTTCCTTCTTCATCATGTGGAGTCC
CATCATCATCACCATCCTCNCATCTTGATCCAAAACTTCCGGCAGGACCTGGNCATCTGG
NCATCCCTTTTCTTCTGGGNNGTNNNNNCACGTTGCNACTCTNCCTAAANCCCATACTGT
ANNANATGNCGCTNNNAGGAANGAATGGAGGAANANTTTTTGNNNNNNNNN
```

...and remove everything past the last N in the beginning and the first N at the end. In other words, to make it look something like this:

```
ACAGACGACGGGCCCTGGCCCCTCGCACACCCTGGACCA
AGTCAATCGCACCCACTTCCCTTTCTTCTCGGATGTCAAGGGCGACCACCGGTTGGTGTT
GAGCGTCGTGGAGACCACCGTTCTGGGGCTCATCTTTGTCGTCTCACTGCTGGGCAACGT
GTGTGCTCTAGTGCTGGTGGCGCGCCGTCGGCGCCGTGGGGCGACAGCCAGCCTGGTGCT
CAACCTCTTCTGCGCGGATTTGCTCTTCACCAGCGCCATCCCTCTAGTGCTCGTCGTGCG
CTGGACTGAGGCCTGGCTGTTGGGGCCCGTCGTCTGCCACCTGCTCTTCTACGTGATGAC
AATGAGCGGCAGCGTCACGATCCTCACACTGGCCGCGGTCAGCCTGGAGCGCATGGTGTG
CATCGTGCGCCTCCGGCGCGGCTTGAGCGGCCCGGGGCGGCGGACTCAGGCGGCACTGCT
GGCTTTCATATGGGGTTACTCGGCGCTCGCCGCGCTGCCCCTCTGCATCTTGTTCCGCGT
GGTCCCGCAGCGCCTTCCCGGCGGGGACCAGGAAATTCCGATTTGCACATTGGATTGGCC
CAACCGCATAGGAGAAATCTCATGGGATGTGTTTTTTGTGACTTTGAACTTCCTGGTGCC
GGGACTGGTCATTGTGATCAGTTACTCCAAAATTTTACAGATCACGAAAGCATCGCGGAA
GAGGCTTACGCTGAGCTTGGCATACTCTGAGAGCCACCAGATCCGAGTGTCCCAACAAGA
CTACCGACTCTTCCGCACGCTCTTCCTGCTCATGGTTTCCTTCTTCATCATGTGGAGTCC
CATCATCATCACCATCCTC
```

How would I do this?

Comment: You lost me at "past the last end in the beginning".

Comment: What is "the last end in the beginning"? And what is "the first N at the end"? (Obviously you don't mean the first `N` after the `TTTTTTG` on the last line, but what _do_ you mean?)

Comment: Your qustion is badly phrased. What is "the last end"? From the data you give, it seems all you want is to strip away the Ns from beginning and end, but then, the massive amount of data you provide makeis it really hard to reason. Please clarify.

Comment: Just a guess.Are you looking for the longest sub string that does not contains an `N`?

Comment: Is it always the same number of `N`s?

Comment: Sorry I meant "past the last N in the beginning" not end.

Comment: No @BurhanKhalid, not always the same number of N's.

Comment: @GeorgeTye: That still doesn't explain anything. What is "the beginning" and what is "the end"? How do we know which N's are beginning N's and which are ending N's? If you can't explain that in English, you can't write it in code.

Comment: Basically the idea is this:
NNNFNNNFNNNFFFFFFFFFFFFFFNNFNN
to
FFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: @GeorgeTye: Don't try to explain it in a comment, edit it into your question.

Answer (score 5):

I think you may be looking for the longest sequence of non-N characters in the input.

Otherwise, you have no rule to distinguish the last `N` in the prefix from the first `N` in the suffix. There is nothing at all different about the `N` you want to start after (before the `ACAGAC…`) and the next `N` (before the `CATCCC`), or, for that matter, the previous one (before the `GN`) except that it picks out the longest sequence. In fact, other than the 10 N's at the very start and the 9 at the very end, there doesn't seem to be anything special about *any* of the N's.

The easiest way to do that is to just grab *all* the sequences and keep the longest:

```
max(s.split('N'), key=len)
```

If you have some additional rule on top of this—e.g., the longest sequence whose length is divisible by three (which in this case is the same thing)—you can do the same basic thing:

```
max((seq for seq in s.split('N') if len(seq) % 3 == 0), key=len)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry I'm a noob programmer.

Comment: (+1) for the creative use of `split()`.

Comment: I have another question that probably doesn't warrant another post. But how do you print out a variable spanning multiple lines? On Python IDLE the print function only prints one line.

Comment: @GeorgeTye: In that case, I'm pretty sure the variable _doesn't_ span multiple lines; it's just longer than 80 characters. If you want to force IDLE to word-wrap the same way the terminal does, you may want to look at the `textwrap` module, or just write your own code to break the output into groups of, say, 78 characters (the biggest number under 80 and divisible by 3) and print each group as its own line.

Answer (score 0):

@abarnert's answer is correct but `str.split()` returns the a list sub strings. Meaning the memory usage is literally `O(N)` (e.g. use tons of memory). This isn't a problem  when you're input is short but when processing DNA sequences, your input is typically very long. To avoid the memory overhead, your need to use a iterator. I recommend the `re`'s `finditer`.

```
import re

_find_n_free_substrings = re.compile(r'[^N]+', re.MULTILINE).finditer

def longest_n_free_substring(string):
    substrings = (match.group(0) for match in _find_n_free_substrings(string))
    return max(substrings, key=len)
```

Comment: Thank you. I like how the variables/functions are easy to understand. This is very helpful.

Comment: IMO my code is more complicated than @abarnrt's. Only prefer my code if you sequences are really long.